# Custom casting to primitive datatype

Tags: java, casting, primitive

I've created my own MutableInt class, which contains a primitive int and some methods for changing the value of this int or just increasing or decreasing it by 1.

I was wondering is there is any way to make this class work like the Integer class, so for example do things like:

```
MutableInt foo = 42;
```

or

```
MutableInt foo = new MutableInt(41);
foo++;
```

or

```
MutableInt foo = new MutableInt(42);
int bar = foo;
```

Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no language support for user-defined conversions in Java. Only the conversions explicitly listed in the specification are supported.